# Manual regression using Maximum Likelihood in Python

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to do linear regression from scratch (only using numpy). I have the following code, but the output makes no sense to me.

```
import numpy as np
```

First I generate some data:

```
# generate data
x1 = np.random.normal(10, 5, 1000)
x2 = np.random.normal(20, 5, 1000)
error = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
y = 3*x1 + 4*x2 + error
X = np.stack((x1,x2)).T
```

From this data generating process it is clear that the correct values are close to 3 and 4. Next I define my class to perform the regression:

```
class GLM:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.weights = np.ones(np.shape(X)[1])
    
    def logLikelihoodDerivative(self, X, y):
        derivative = np.dot(y - np.exp(np.dot(X, self.weights)), X)
        # derivative = -(self.weights)**2 + 3
            
        print(self.weights) # to observe how weights are updated
        return derivative
       
    def fit(self, X, y, numberOfIterations=10000):
        for _ in range(0, numberOfIterations):
            self.gradientAscent(X, y)

    def gradientAscent(self, X, y, learningRate=0.0001):
        gradient = self.logLikelihoodDerivative(X, y)
        self.weights = self.weights + learningRate * gradient
        return self.weights
```

Now I apply my model:

```
test = GLM()
test.fit(X, y)
print("My output:     ", test.weights[0], " and ", test.weights[1])
```

Finally I try to check my outcome with the Python library `statsmodels`:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
check = sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
print("Correct output:", check.params[0], " and ", check.params[1])
```

(Note: I am assuming a Poisson distribution).

In the code above the weights explode and become inf/-inf very quickly. I do not understand why. As a check, I also added the artificial derivative `-(self.weights)**2 + 3` (-x^2 + 3) which obviously has a maximum at 3. However, the calculated weights with this artificial derivative are around 1.7 and 1.7.

What is going wrong in my code?